# Using a Mono Reference assembler (tweetsharp)

Tags: c#, mono, tweetsharp

I developed an app that uses Tweetsharp, now I would like to convert that app with mono but I am kinda new to this world!
I downloaded mono, monodevelop and moma and I noticed that in Tweetsharp there is a solution for mono.
I tried to build it with either visual studio and monodevelop but both give me errors. So what is the right procedure to generate a reference for mono applications? 
And the reference has to be used with monodevelop or I can use it also in VS using a directive?

Answer (score 0):

From its GitHub history we can see there are few commits to the Mono folder now (Feb 1 2012),

https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/commits/master/src/mono

Therefore, I think this library is not yet Mono compatible. If you are not capable of helping port it to Mono, you would have to wait till its authors finish the port, or find another library in this field who supports Mono.

Comment: I am not sure about that, I'll try to ask to the developer!